# dataframe bool index after sampling has error 'indices are out-of-bounds'

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df[df['my_col'] == 1]
```

is ok. But if I sampled it:

```
df[df.sample(frac=1)['my_col'] == 1]
```

I will get an error `'indices are out-of-bounds'`. My index is `timestampe`, which may lead the error. Since it does not happen for integer index.

Could I ask how to solve it?

Comment: could you show a sample dataframe to reproduce the problem.